# Polynomial Divison of unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

How to complete this $$P(X)=\frac{2x^4-7x^3+5x^2+ax+b }{ 2x^2+x-1}$$
so that the division is without a remainder?

When it is divided it gives two equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the division gives $P(x)$ without leaving a remainder. That means that both the factors of the denominator, $2x^2 + x -1$ will be factors of the numerator, $2x^4-7x^3+5x^2+ax+b$.

So factorise the quadratic in the denominator using the quadratic formula. Get it into the form $2(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)$, where $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ represent the two roots of $2x^2 + x -1$.

Now put each of $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ into the numerator expression and equate it to zero in turn. This is Factor Theorem being applied. You get a system of two linear simultaneous equations you can then solve for $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to solve this problem.

The first way would consist in the polynomial division to compute the remainder. This gives $$P(x)=\frac{2x^4-7x^3+5x^2+ax+b }{ 2x^2+x-1}=x^2-4x+5+\frac{(a-9) x+(b+5)}{2 x^2+x-1}$$ Since the remainder must be zero, then $a=9$ and $b=-5$.

The second way would consist is writing that, since the remainer is zero,$$2x^4-7x^3+5x^2+ax+b=(2x^2+x-1)(\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma)$$ Expand the rhs and move everything to the same side. This should lead to $$(2-2 \alpha ) x^4-x^3 (\alpha +2 \beta +7)+x^2
   (\alpha -\beta -2 \gamma +5)+x (a+\beta -\gamma )+(b+\gamma)$$ Now cancel all coefficients and so you find $$2-2\alpha=0$$ $$\alpha +2 \beta +7=0$$ $$\alpha -\beta -2 \gamma +5=0$$  $$a+\beta -\gamma=0$$ $$b+\gamma=0$$ from which the solutions, easy to obtain from top to bottom, are $\alpha=1$,$\beta=-4$,$\gamma=5$,$a=9$,$b=-5$.